# Applying if statement for the column in pandas

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas

I have a Probability column, some of the values are greater then 1.
I am trying to iterate over every row of that column and change values to 0.99 for all > 0.99. Also I need to see if column 1 is equal to column 2. If yes Probability must be 0. And if column 3 is greater than 11 => set Probability to 0.

I have tried next things and these doesn't work. All of them tell me that my syntax is invalid:

```
test['Probability'] = test.apply(lambda r: '0.99' if r['Probability] == '0.99')
```

I also tried to write the next. And it doesn't work as well:

```
test['Probability'] = ['0.99' if a > '0.99',
                       '0.0' if b == c,
                       '0.0' if d > '11'
                        for a, b, c, d in zip(
                          list(test['Probability']),
                          list(test['Column 1']),
                          list(test['Column 2']),
                          list(test['Column 3'])
                        )]


 Probability  Column 1   Column 2  Column 3
    1.13         2           2        13
    0            34          12       2 
    0.1042       4           4        5
    0.8          1           54       3
    0.03         1           3        8
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting quotes around your values (`'0.99'`) unless they are strings. If you want to test if a numeric column is greater than 0.99, then it's `r['Probability'] > 0.99`, not `r['Probabliity'] > '0.99'`

Comment: rather than truncating probabilities, shouldn't you be asking yourself why they are greater than 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just write simple statements such as below. Hope this helps!

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df =   pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(10),'b':np.random.randn(10),'c':np.random.randn(10),'probability':np.random.randn(10)})
    df.b[0:4]=df.a[0:4]
    df.probability[2:7]=1
    df.c[8:10]=12

    #Set probability=0 where probability >0
    df['probability'][df['probability'] > 0.99] = 0.99

    #Set probability=0 where  column a = column b
    df['probability'] [df['a']==df['b']] = 0

    #Set probability=0 where  column c > 11
    df['probability'] [df['c']>11] = 0

    print df

      a         b          c            probability
      0.572290  0.572290  -0.479909     0.000000
     -1.046103 -1.046103  -1.640504     0.000000
     -0.395438 -0.395438  -0.506313     0.000000
      0.722509  0.722509   0.408912     0.000000
      1.293353  0.337776  -0.168297     0.990000
     -1.227133  0.723976   0.878665     0.990000
     -0.797757  0.915007  -1.672020     0.990000
      0.622970  0.030374   1.700830    -0.977129
     -0.831948 -0.084003  12.000000     0.000000
      0.285812 -0.110511  12.000000     0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

First task, use a boolean mask to find all values that meet your condition and assign the new value, this is a generic scenario I don't quite understand what you are trying to do exactly:

```
In [14]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(10),'b':np.random.randn(10),'c':np.random.randn(10)})
df
Out[14]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.015551  1.861532  0.028729
1  0.567215  2.193496 -1.070560
2  0.209520 -0.425338 -0.619085
3 -0.065431 -0.016801  0.382174
4  1.832790 -0.488823 -0.674983
5 -0.737770 -2.596719  0.121268
6  0.000486  0.022497  0.586638
7 -1.006143  0.808605  0.248115
8  1.409578 -0.467725 -1.249656
9 -0.776510  0.895553  0.233154
In [15]:

df[df>0.99] = 0.99
df
Out[15]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.015551  0.990000  0.028729
1  0.567215  0.990000 -1.070560
2  0.209520 -0.425338 -0.619085
3 -0.065431 -0.016801  0.382174
4  0.990000 -0.488823 -0.674983
5 -0.737770 -2.596719  0.121268
6  0.000486  0.022497  0.586638
7 -1.006143  0.808605  0.248115
8  0.990000 -0.467725 -1.249656
9 -0.776510  0.895553  0.233154
```

Task 2 + 3.

```
In [19]:
# create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3,4],'b':[1,2,3,4],'c':[1,22,11,11], 'probability':np.random.randn(4)})
df
Out[19]:
   a  b   c  probability
0  1  1   1     0.273157
1  1  2  22    -0.027685
2  3  3  11    -0.051091
3  4  4  11     0.630943
In [20]:
# use loc with a boolean condition to set just the rows that meet your condition
df.loc[df['a']==df['b'],'probability']=0
df
Out[20]:
   a  b   c  probability
0  1  1   1     0.000000
1  1  2  22    -0.027685
2  3  3  11     0.000000
3  4  4  11     0.000000
In [21]:
# now do the same for the other column
df.loc[df['c']>=11, 'probability'] = 0
df
Out[21]:
   a  b   c  probability
0  1  1   1            0
1  1  2  22            0
2  3  3  11            0
3  4  4  11            0
```

Your attempts didn't work:

```
test['Probability'] = test.apply(lambda r: '0.99' if r['Probability] == '0.99')
```

this won't work because you are calling apply on the df, naturally this will iterate over the columns and you are trying to check the probability column it's unclear to me what you are trying to do here, are you checking just the probability column or all columns?

Your list comprehension makes little sense you're just reconstructing the df and trying to compare the values but it's trying to assign some tuple as the new calculated value.